# Uncheck radio buttons when the close button is clicked

Tags: javascript

I'm currently have a modal with some radio buttons (".modal-options"), and a close modal button.
Im trying to make it so when the close button is clicked, all the clicked radio buttons become unchecked.
current code is below. Console is saying that removeAttr is not a function...? thanks

```html
 <p class='information'> Cancel Appointment? </p>
        <div class="modal-flex">
          <%= f.radio_button :delete_appointment, :true %>
          <%= f.label :delete_appointment_true, "Yes", class: "modal-options cancel" %>
     
          <%= f.radio_button :delete_appointment, :false %>
          <%= f.label :delete_appointment_false, "No", class: "modal-options cancel" %>
          
        </div>
```

```html
  <p class="close"> <%= t(".close")  %> </p>
```

```js
var close = document.querySelector(".close");
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".modal-options");
close.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  buttons.forEach(function(button) {
    button.removeAttr('checked');
  });
})
```

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML....

Comment: Usually, the error is fired when the DOM element is not getting selected properly. Providing the relevant html file can be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`.removeAttr()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) is jQuery method. The equivalent JavaScript method is [`remove​Attribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute)

Though, I prefer using the *checked* property:

```
button.checked = false;
```

You are targeting the label, instead you should target the *radio* button:

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".modal-flex input[type=radio]");
```

Comment: thanks, ive made your change but nothing is happening. Im not getting any errors

Comment: @b.herring, you should target the radio button..... updated the answer, please check:)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `removeAttr` isn't a function on HTML Elements; you meant `removeAttribute` ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute)).

Secondly, for unchecking an input, you'd want `input.checked = false` instead. The reason removeAttribute doesn't work is because if you inspect the input element, you will see that no 'checked' attribute is being added or removed when toggling. 'Checked' is a property, not an attribute; the distinction is important in this case and when getting into custom elements.

```js
  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelector('input').checked = false;
  });
```

```html
<input type="checkbox">
<button>uncheck</button>
```

Comment: I think the op might be mixing jQuery with vanilla Javascript

Comment: Note that using `document.querySelector('input')` will grab only the first `<input>` element on the page, which might not even be a checkbox.